# How to receive multiple values in Erlang program from C program?

Tags: erlang, robotics

I am using Erlang for driving robot.

I am **reading sensor values in C program and want to send these sensor values(multiple sensor values) to Erlang program**  where I can perform computation and  control robot.
In progam given in Erlang book we can send multiple argument but **we get back only one argument as result.**
for sending X and Y to C program:

```
Port ! {self(), {command, [50,X,Y]}}
```

In result:

```
{Port,{data, Data}} ->
```

we got only one argument Data(buff[0]).

**Is there any way to receive multiple argument in Erlang program like buff[0], buff[1], buff[2]..and so on.**
 please suggest me some way of achieving this...

Comment: Will Erlang return an object?  If it will, create a composite object containing the necessary data points and return that.

Comment: Why is this marked community wiki?

Answer (score 4):

Just constuct and return a tuple of 3 and then return the binary of that and patternmatch it straight in the answer. You can construct tuples and lists by using the ei modules. See http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erl_interface/index.html (module ei) for how to do that and look at http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erl_interface/users_guide.html for the user guide.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your C file and send back a binary for example,

what kind of driver are you using?

Comment: i have tried using both C port and Port driver(linked in driver).

Answer (score 0):

you can use ei_decode_X where X is the type of the value that you want the decoded value to be. Ideally when sending it from erlang, you should do a term_to_binary and then transport it.